# How to read in table that depends on two sets previously defined

Tags: linear-programming, glpk

I am optimizing the choice of letters with the surfaces they require in the laser cutter to maximize the total frequency of words that they can form. I wrote this program for GLPK:

```
set unicodes;
param surfaces{u in unicodes};
table data IN "CSV" "surfaces.csv": unicodes <- [u], surfaces~s;

set words;
param frequency{w in words}, integer;
table data IN "CSV" "words.csv": words <- [word], frequency~frequency;
```

Then I want to give a table giving each word the count of each character with its unicode. The sets `words` and `unicodes` are already defined. According to page 42 of the manual, I can omit the set and the delimiter:

> `table name alias IN driver arg . . . arg : set <- [fld, ..., fld], par~fld, ...,  par~fld;`
>
> ...
>
> set is the name of an optional simple set called control set. It can be omitted along with the
>   delimiter <-;

So I write this:

```
param spectrum{w in words, u in unicodes} >= 0;
table data IN "CSV" "spectrum.csv": words~word, unicodes~unicode, spectrum~spectrum;
```

I get the error:

```
Reading model section from lp...
lp:19: delimiter <- missing where expected
Context: ..., u in unicodes } >= 0 ; table data IN '...' '...' : words ~
```

If I write:

```
table data IN "CSV" "spectrum.csv": [words, unicodes] <- [word, unicode], spectrum~spectrum;
```

I get the error:

```
Reading model section from lp...
lp:19: syntax error in table statement
Context: ...} >= 0 ; table data IN '...' '...' : [ words , unicodes ] <-
```

How can I read in a table with data on two sets already defined?

*Notes*: the CSV files are similar to this:

`surfaces.csv`:

```
u,s
41,1
42,1.5
43,1.2
```

`words.csv`:

```
word,frequency
abc,10
```

`spectrum.csv`:

```
word,unicode,spectrum
abc,1,41
abc,2,42
abc,3,43
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer with [AMPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMPL), A Mathematical Programming Language, which is a superset of GNU MathProg. I needed to define a set with the links between `words` and `unicodes`, and use that set as the control set when reading the table:

```
set links within {words, unicodes};
param spectrum{links} >= 0;
table data IN "CSV" "spectrum.csv": links <- [word, unicode], spectrum~spectrum;
```

And now I get:

```
...
INTEGER OPTIMAL SOLUTION FOUND
Time used:   0.0 secs
Memory used: 0.1 Mb (156430 bytes)
```

The "optional set" in the documentation is still misleading and I filed a bug report. For reference, the AMPL book is [free to download](https://ampl.com/resources/the-ampl-book/chapter-downloads/) and I used the transportation model scattered in page 47 in Section 3.2, page 173 in section 10.1, and page 179 in section 10.2.